# Stack cache builds with various flags

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I have two different build commands that I use for my project

```
stack build -j8 --profile
```

and

```
stack build -j8  --ghc-options -DVERBOSE_SOLVING
```

There are hundreds of files in my projects. Whenever I change from one to the other command everything is rebuilt. Is there a way to keep the build increments of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `stack` where to keep the cache via `--work-dir`. The default is `<project root>/.stack-work`, but you can specify separate directories for your different build modes:

```
stack build -j8 --profile --work-dir .stack-work-profile

stack build -j8 --ghc-options -DVERBOSE_SOLVING --work-dir .stack-work-verbose-solving
```

I don't think there is a way to have `stack` automatically figure out different caches based on flags. If you *really* need this, you could whip up a script that would take a hash of the flag combination and redirect work-dir to `.stack-work-<hash>` or something.